# Reduction of HP to L3

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

I want to make the following reduction:

HP is the Halting Problem: HP = {w#x | w, x ∈ {0,1}* , Mw halts on input x}
w is the binary coded turing machine Mw.
L3 is the problem which asks, if M accepts exactly 3 inputs.

I know HP is not decidable, so I want to show that L3 is not decidable also:

HP ≤ L3

How can I make the reduction? The problem is that I don't know how I should proof that L3 accepts exactly just 3 inputs.

Comment: You can use Rice's theorem.

Comment: Yes because the 3 inputs are not a non-trivial characteristic, you are right. But what if I want to show the reduction. I'm really wondering about how to solve it.

Comment: Repeat the proof of Rice's theorem, with your language replacing the arbitrary non-trivial language in the theorem.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot follow you. I was thinking about creating a Turing Machine Mw' running Mw as a subroutine.